# How OrientDB links physically work (to give O(1) relationship complexity and reference update)

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

How OrientDB links physically work?

For example, if two nodes are connected they know each other physical position (given by the cluster id and node id in the cluster), what happens to the physical references when I move one of them elsewhere? Everything is updated automatically? There is some source of information about that?

Same thing about the O(1) relationship complexity, I don't find nothing about that (only "OrientDB handles relationships as physical links to the records and assigns them only once, when the edge is created. That is, O(1)").

The only information I found are and nothing more

- http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Relationships.html#the-problem-with-joins

I need more specific information about that.

**UPDATE**: found the information I needed thanks to Luca Garulli

- Physical position update: MOVE VERTEX SQL command
- O(1) complexity: http://www.slideshare.net/lvca/how-graph-databases-started-the-multi-model-revolution (key point at 33)

Comment: Solved in the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how much detail you want to get down, but other information about RID and Computational Complexity, you can find them at these links:

- [2.1 tutorial](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Tutorial-Record-ID.html)
- [[Design question] Record IDs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/orient-database/record$20ID/orient-database/KpruuOvI7a4/FEENcwipnfUJ)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not exactly what I was looking for but the second link pointed out some interesting things